# Extract specific words from a log file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

Existing Logfile :

```
00:00:00.035790 0x7ff488dfa700>INFO: Session(ABC_BETA -1): 0.000494 Type Info
00:24:00.035799 0x7ff488dfa700>DEBUG: Session(ABC_BETA -1): 1.000000 Type Debug
01:02:00.035801 0x7ff488dfa700>INFO: Session(2NDStage -1): 0.000133 Type Info
21:00:00.035803 0x7ff488dfa700>INFO: Session(jOHN -1): 0.000140 Type Info
23:59:00.035805 0x7ff488dfa700>INFO: Session(NIRVANA -1): 0.003880 Type Info
```

Expected result:

```
00:00:00 INFO ABC_BETA
00:24:00 DEBUG ABC_BETA
01:02:00 INFO 2NDStage
21:00:00 INFO jOHN
23:59:00 INFO NIRVANA
```

I was able to extract this using a combination of sed, cut as below :

```
sed 's/[\.\>\)\( \]/{/g'<testfile.log|cut -d "{" -f 1,4,6|sed 's/{/ /g'|sed 's/: / /g'
```

Just wondering if there was a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Replace the parts you don't need with one space: `sed 's/\..*>/ /; s/: .*(/ /; s/ -1).*//' file`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[.> (]|: ' '{print $1, $4, $6}' file
00:00:00 INFO ABC_BETA
00:24:00 DEBUG ABC_BETA
01:02:00 INFO 2NDStage
21:00:00 INFO jOHN
23:59:00 INFO NIRVANA
```

Answer (score 1):

All sed

```
sed -re 's/([0-9:]{8})[^>]+>([^:]+): Session[(]([^ ]+) .*[)].*/\1 \2 \3/' test.txt
```

Result:

```
00:00:00 INFO ABC_BETA
00:24:00 DEBUG ABC_BETA
01:02:00 INFO 2NDStage
21:00:00 INFO jOHN
23:59:00 INFO NIRVANA
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` idea:

```
sed -En 's/^([^.]*).*>([^:]*).*\(([^ ]*).*$/\1 \2 \3/p' test.log
```

Where:

- `-En` - enable `E`xtended regex and (`-n`) disable printing of pattern space
- `^([^.]*)` - 1st capture group: from start of line => everything that is not a period (`.`)
- `.*>` - everything after 1st capture group up to/including `>`
- `([^:]*)` - 2nd capture group: everything that is not a colon (`:`)
- `.*\(` - everything after 2nd capture group up to/including literal `(`
- `([^ ]*)` - 3rd capture group: everything that is not a space
- `.*$` - everthing after the 3rd capture group up to the end of the line
- `\1 \2 \3/p` - print our capture groups w/ single space as delimiter

This generates:

```
00:00:00 INFO ABC_BETA
00:24:00 DEBUG ABC_BETA
01:02:00 INFO 2NDStage
21:00:00 INFO jOHN
23:59:00 INFO NIRVANA
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\.[^(]*\((\S+).* (\S+)$/ \U\2\E \1/' file
```

Pattern match and use `\U` and `\E` to uppercase the last field only.